# How to correctly display html-page on all mobile devices/browsers

Tags: xhtml, browser, mobile, wap, wurfl

I'm currently working on survey project where users answer surveys from they mobile phones. I need to display a vary basic pages with one question on each page, but I need to make sure they are correctly displayed on all mobile phones, because user can have wap browser, "normal" browser like opera mini and probably something else. So my question is:

- Do I need to use special software (e.g. [wurfl](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/))?
- If so, what libraries can you recommend?

Thanks.

Comment: Even if you find a library you will still find that you need to test your page(s) on all target browsers. Call it fact of life, or hard-earned experience.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you [xHTML Mobile Profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML_Mobile_Profile). If you want to support very old phones then [WML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Markup_Language) too. WURFL is great database for discover capabilities of phones.